# Deadlock behaviour having 3 threads with wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 Threads, all 3 doing the same thing "[...]" (e.g. writing to a list, on which we synchronize):

```
public void run(){
  long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
  while(System.currentTimeMillis - time < 10000){
    synchronized(object){
      [...]
      object.notifyAll();
      object.wait();
    }
  }
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread.getName() + " just finished");
}
```

What I found curious, is that when one thread exits the while-loop, a deadlock occurs. My problem is not that it happened, as it is exactly what I was testing, but when it occured. Shouldn't the deadlock happen after two threads are finished because there is one left that cannot be notified by any of the finished two?
Of course there is a chance that two threads call their "wait" at the same time, so we get a deadlock after just one finished thread because the two waiting ones cannot be woken up by the finished one, but I have run the test numerous times and the result is always the same: Deadlock after just one finished thread.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the thing the threads are waiting for exactly? See [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/how-to-work-with-wait-notify-and-notifyall-in-java/) for some docs on how to actually wait for something.

Comment: In this context there is nothing specific they are waiting for. I noticed this behaviour in another context and wanted to write a simple test for it. The question is a bit general, but I wasn't sure how to phrase it. 
I thought that having three threads, with wait and notify in this order, will only cause a deadlock when all but one threads are gone, as there will almost allways be one to notify the others.  
I know that waiting just for the sake of waiting is not sensible. Maybe I'm just spending too much time thinking about things that will not usually happen (i.e.wait without a condition)

Comment: It just won't work. If there's nothing they're waiting for, there's no way for them to know if it's already happened or not. If you wait for something that has already happened, you'll be waiting forever. So this is a design that absolutely cannot possibly work except perhaps by luck. To use wait/notify you *must* maintain the state of the thing that is being waited for. You cannot wait for nothing in particular, it will not work.

Comment: ok, I'll remember that. So the thing I wanted to take a look at didn't really make much sense to begin with. thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` function will wait whether there's something to wait for or not. Before you call `wait`, you must check whether the thing you want to wait for has already happened -- that's why you're in a `synchronized` block, so that you hold the lock that protects the shared state that you are waiting for.

You will never get `wait`/`notifyAll` to work without some shared state that you are waiting to reach some particular state. You must use the lock to protect that shared state, and you must check its state before calling `wait`. Otherwise, you will always have possible races including the one you are seeing where you wait for something to happen even though it has already happened, thus waiting forever.